# How can I parse a XML data in CFML

Tags: xml, api, parsing, cfml

When I tried to parse an XML data, but I get this error:

```
Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

This is my code:

```
<cfset the_url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/210456?format=xml&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'>

<cfhttp url="#the_url#" method="get" result="Results" timeout="999">

<cfset asd = XmlParse(Results)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `XmlParse()` function is already correct.

Your issue is with the `Results` variable. That variable is *not* the XML itself but a structure holding information of the HTTP request/response. See the examples at https://cfdocs.org/cfhttp.

So to access the XML returned by the request you need to access `Results.fileContent`.

Additional tip: Put your HTTP request and the `XmlParse()` line in a `<cftry>`/`<cfcatch>` block in order to catch any exceptions thrown by the request or while parsing the XML.